# Disable Kodi's mini-player. Force Kodi to stop playback when you press "Exit"

Tags: android-tv, kodi

**tl;dr** *How to prevent Kodi from continuing playback when you press <kbd>Exit</kbd> button on remote controller?*

---

When you're playing a video file in any Android TV player that I have tested so far (about dozens) when you press <kbd>Exit</kbd> button on remote controller, your player **stops playback**. This is as obvious as it can be. "Exit" means "Stop".

Someone at Kodi's development team doesn't understand that and figured out that it will be so cool to **continue playback** when in Kodi 19.3 user presses <kbd>Exit</kbd> button. Kodi truly exits to the menu, but continues to play current movie in the background in something that I call a "mini-player".

This is as stupid as it can be, because usually I need to browse 5-6 menu screens until I get back to the home screen when I can turn this damn thing off.

Is there any configuration switch that controls this? Is there any way to disable this stupid behavior?

I think I have browsed each and every configuration section in *Expert* mode and found nothing. So I just want to get myself confirmed that I must learn myself to live with this.